# GnuWin32 Awk in powershell script weird output (First char replaced by a space)

Tags: windows, bash, batch-file, powershell, awk

I have a `awk` command that produces weird output when called from a PowerShell script. It truncates the first character of each line. If I use it in a regular batch file or in a cmd.exe terminal it works as expected. It also works as expected under Linux.

Can someone explain why, and if possible how to fix it?

**This is the command I try to execute from PowerShell:**

```
cat .\corpus_tagged.txt | gawk 'NF>0' | gawk '{bo=$2\"#\"$3; printf \"%s %s %s\",$1,$2,$3; for (i=5;i<=NF; i+=3) {if (bo!=$i\"#\"$(i+1)) printf \" %s %s\",$i,$(i+1);} printf \"\n\"}'
```

**This is the command that works from batch/cmd.exe**

```
cat corpus_tagged.txt | gawk "NF>0" | gawk "{bo=$2\"#\"$3; printf \"%s %s %s\",$1,$2,$3; for (i=5;i<=NF; i+=3) {if (bo!=$i\"#\"$(i+1)) printf \" %s %s\",$i,$(i+1);} printf \"\n\"}"
```

**The awk script in an easier to read format**

```
{
    bo=$2"#"$3;
    printf "%s %s %s",$1,$2,$3;
    for (i=5;i<=NF; i+=3) 
    {
        if (bo!=$i"#"$(i+1)) 
            printf " %s %s",$i,$(i+1);
    }
    printf "\n";
}
```

**My input has the following content:** (corpus_tagged.txt file)

```
J' je PP1CSN00 # je PP1CSN00 1 
aime aimer VMIP1S0 # aimer VMIP1S0 0,49045643153527  aimer VMIP3S0 0,49045643153527  aimer VMM02S0 0,0174273858921162  aimer VMSP1S0 0,000829875518672199  aimer VMSP3S0 0,000829875518672199 
les le DA0CP0 # le DA0CP0 0,900251352385116  les PP3CPA00 0,0997486476148844 
ananas ananas NCMN000 # ananas NCMN000 1 
. . Fp # . Fp 1 
Il il PP3MSN00 # il PP3MSN00 1 
aime aimer VMIP3S0 # aimer VMIP1S0 0,49045643153527  aimer VMIP3S0 0,49045643153527  aimer VMM02S0 0,0174273858921162  aimer VMSP1S0 0,000829875518672199  aimer VMSP3S0 0,000829875518672199 
les le DA0CP0 # le DA0CP0 0,900251352385116  les PP3CPA00 0,0997486476148844 
chats chat NCMP000 # chat NCMP000 1 
. . Fp # . Fp 1
```

**This is my expected output:**

```
J' je PP1CSN00
aime aimer VMIP1S0 aimer VMIP3S0 aimer VMM02S0 aimer VMSP1S0 aimer VMSP3S0
les le DA0CP0 les PP3CPA00
ananas ananas NCMN000
. . Fp
Il il PP3MSN00
aime aimer VMIP3S0 aimer VMIP1S0 aimer VMM02S0 aimer VMSP1S0 aimer VMSP3S0
les le DA0CP0 les PP3CPA00
chats chat NCMP000
. . Fp
```

**And finally, the output when calling from powershell (first char of each line is replaced by a space character**

```
 ' je PP1CSN00
 ime aimer VMIP1S0 aimer VMIP3S0 aimer VMM02S0 aimer VMSP1S0 aimer VMSP3S0
 es le DA0CP0 les PP3CPA00
 nanas ananas NCMN000
  . Fp
 l il PP3MSN00
 ime aimer VMIP3S0 aimer VMIP1S0 aimer VMM02S0 aimer VMSP1S0 aimer VMSP3S0
 es le DA0CP0 les PP3CPA00
 hats chat NCMP000
  . Fp
```

Comment: I tried your PS one-liner and got the expected output.

Comment: Don't you think it might be easier for us to read your script if you didn't cram every statement together onto a single line? Anyway, the usual advice is to just put your awk script into a file and invoke it as `awk -f script` to avoid the DOS quoting (and other?) issues.

Comment: @EdMorton I have the same behavior if I invoke it by placing my commands in a script file and invoke it with `awk -f`. I'll edit the question with an easier to read version of the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem finally was an old version of Gnu Awk on my path.

Seems that GNU Awk 3.0.4 has some bug with the powershell environment that GNU Awk 3.1.6 does not have.

Having removed 3.0.4 from my environment fixed it.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. By the way, you don't need 2 awks in a pipe, as `gawk 'NF>0' | gawk '{bo=$2...}'` can be reduced to just `gawk 'NF{bo=$2...}'`, also you don't need the `cat` as `cat file | awk '...'` can be reduced to just `awk '...' file`.